# Heaviness in eternal recurence

Tags: metaphysics, nietzsche, determinism

In *The Unbearable Lightness of Being*, it is said that:

> In the world of eternal return the weight of unbearable responsibility lies heavy on every move we make. That is why Nietzsche called the idea of eternal return the heaviest of burdens (das schwerste Gewicht).

What is so heavy about living a life over and over again?

Wouldn't it be boring, maybe by realizing through seeing the process like watching a film, even watching yourself live repeatedly? Wouldn't you become indifferent and uncaring to the process?

Comment: This is not freedom like what sartre says,you are following something.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Answer (score 2):

Nietzsche's eternal return is a view that there are certain inevitable highs and lows in life that happen no matter how many times life is lived.

As [Emrys Westacott writes](https://www.thoughtco.com/nietzsches-idea-of-the-eternal-recurrence-2670659), the "*heavy responsibility* "(?) is to take a positive attitude to this predicament.

> the ultimate expression of a life-affirming attitude: to want this
>   life, with all its pain and boredom and frustration, again and again.
>   This thought connects with the dominant theme of Book IV of "The Gay
>   Science," which is the importance of being a “yea-sayer,” a
>   life-affirmer, and of embracing *amor fati* (love of one’s fate).
>
> This is also how the idea is presented in "Thus Spoke Zarathustra."
>   Zarathustra’s being able to embrace eternal recurrence is the ultimate
>   expression of his love for life and his desire to remain “faithful to
>   the earth.”

Comment: i always found nietzsche's interest in the higher men somewhat strange. not from a psychological perspective, but the need to self legislate coupled with (right?) a need for higher types to be happy

Comment: @another_name I guess embracing one's fate - not just one's own, but the fate of being human - is a more positive attitude than otherwise.  Could be difficult in some circumstances.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks